# NULL sets default value or nullability?

Tags: sql, t-sql, nullable, create-table

In a `CREATE TABLE` I see the following for an existing table:

```
[FooColumn] NUMERIC (19, 3) NULL,
```

I am a total n00b to T-SQL and only a very infrequent user of normal SQL. Does the `NULL` mean that the field defaults to null, or that the field is nullable?

For e.g. does the following make sense, meaning the latter case is true, `[FooColumn] NUMERIC (19, 3) NULL DEFAULT 1.5,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the field is nullable. It will default to NULL. Per your update, to create a decimal field that defaults to 1.5 and is also nullable:

```
[FooColumn] NUMERIC (19, 3) DEFAULT 1.5 NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it defaults to NULL if it is mentioned as null alone as below:

```
create table #footable1(foocolumn numeric(19,3) null)

insert into #footable1 default values
```

If you provide explicit defaults it will have that value instead of null

```
create table #footable(foocolumn numeric(19,3) null default 1.3)

insert into #footable default values
```

You will have result of 1.3